Mobile robot trajectory optimizer
I am currently looking for some tool/library/inspiration for trajectory generation.
I am given a set of waypoints (red, as created by a path planner).
I want to obtain a continuous trajectory $\Pi\left(t\right)$ from those waypoints, which gives the pose (SE2), velocity, and acceleration of the robot (unicycle model) at a given time $t$, such that the robot's dynamic bounds on $v\in [0, v_\max]$, $\omega\in [\omega_\min, \omega_\max]$, $a\in [a_\min, a_\max]$, and $\alpha\in [\alpha_\min, \alpha_\max]$ are note violated. Here, $v$ and $a$ are the robot's forward velocity and acceleration, respectively (expressed in the robot's coordinate frame).
I assume the way this is done, is that you generate some sort of a sequence of splines and then compute a time parametrization. While I have found something in literature for mobile robots Sprunk et al and something for n-joint manupulators Toppra Github, Time-Optimal Path Parameterization, I am still looking for something that is applicable to mobile robots. My overall goal is to generate dynamically feasible reference for a MPC controller.


there is a good starting c++ and a python implantation of general use path planning algorithms for mobile robots, that contain spline or Bspline generation option, trajectory constraints are not dynamically set in theses implantations, as far as i remember, but you can modify the code to include your custom constraints or change them dynamically while the robot is moving at each step.
CppRobotics
pythonRobotics
